# Variable YYY originally saved as a XXX cannot be instantiated as an object and will be read in as a uint32

Tags: matlab, recover

I've made a mistake and recorded a bunch of important data using a class definition that I can't find anymore. The methods are not important, I just want the data; a struct conversion would be fine.

Is there any way I can recover this?

Googling it did not help.

Comment: IIRC, you would need to have the class definition on the path to resolve that error...

Comment: Can you remember the class definition enough that the properties should align? You might be able to create a spoof class which isn't the same as the original, but is enough of a shell to load the property values into.

Comment: good ideas, I will try them and let you know

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution is to create a new class that overloads the [`loadobj`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/loadobj.html) method. See [here](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_oop/understanding-the-save-and-load-process.html) for more information regarding the load process for classes.

I replicated your problem by creating a class:

```matlab
classdef myclass
   properties
      Prop1
      Prop2
      Prop3
   end
   methods
       function obj = myclass(a,b,c)
           obj.Prop1 = a;
           obj.Prop2 = b;
           obj.Prop3 = c;
       end
   end
end
```

Then I created an object of this class and saving it to a file "x.mat":

```matlab
x = myclass('a',56,[1,2,3]);
save x
```

Next, I deleted the `myclass` file and did `clear classes`. This put me in your situation.

I then created a new `myclass` class that overloads the `loadobj` method:

```matlab
classdef myclass
   properties
       data
   end
   methods (Static)
       function obj = loadobj(s)
           obj = myclass;
           obj.data = s;
       end
   end
end
```

Note how it doesn't know any of the original properties. This does not matter. If any of the original properties is missing when loading an object from a MAT-file, `loadobj` will be called with `s` being a `struct` containing all the properties of the original object.

With this new class definition, `load x` created an object `x` of class `myclass`, where `x.data` was a struct containing the properties of the object saved in "x.mat".

Comment: Very nice way to recover content ... as far as I remember matlab in previous versions was anyway returning saved structure data "as is" instead of an uint32 ... so sad it is not providing built-in solution like `load(...., 'ForceLoadUnknowObjectsAsStruct', true)`