# Variable 'Ptot_pdf' originally saved as a prob.NormalDistribution cannot be instantiated as an object and will be read in as a uint32

Tags: matlab, uint32, matlab-class

I want to run the [STORM package](https://github.com/blissville71/STORM/tree/1.0) in Matlab, but I receive this error:

STORM('Validation',1,30,2,'ptotC','stormsC','ptot2C','storms2C','ETC')

```
Warning: Variable 'Ptot_pdf' originally saved as a prob.NormalDistribution cannot be 
 instantiated as an object and will be read in as a uint32. 
 > In STORM (line 225) 
  Error using var (line 66)
  Invalid data type. First input argument must be single or double.

  Error in std (line 51)
  y = sqrt(var(varargin{:}));

  Error in STORM (line 227)
  sigma = std(Ptot_pdf);
```

I tried this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57922957/variable-yyy-originally-saved-as-a-xxx-cannot-be-instantiated-as-an-object-and-w), which was accepted 4 years ago, but it didn't work for me. I am receiving the same error:

```
classdef NormalDistribution
properties
   data
end
methods (Static)
    function obj = loadobj(s)
       obj = NormalDistribution;
       obj.data = s;
     end
 end
end
>> NormalDistribution

 ans = 

 NormalDistribution with properties:

  data: []

 >> load Ptot_pdf
Warning: Variable 'Ptot_pdf' originally saved as a prob.NormalDistribution cannot be 
instantiated as an object and will be read in as a uint32.
```